# regular expression for remove duplicate slashes

Tags: php, regex

How are you? I have the next task. I have a lot of strings that can contain duplicate slashes. I need to replace duplicate slashes to one slash (any count of slashes), but when the next symbols found after slashes (quote, double quote, NUL (NULL byte)) - all slashes should be removed. Thanks. My language - PHP. Some tests:

```
$s1 = 'test\\\\string';
// test\string
$s2 = 'test\\\\\"\\\\\'\\\\string';
// test"'\string
$s3 = 'test\\string\\\\\"';
// test\string"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
preg_replace("~\\\\+([\"\'\\x00\\\\])~", "$1", $string);
```

to replace arbitrary amounts of `\` with just one `\`.

The pattern consist of arbitrary initial backslahes `\\\\+` and a following symbol that is one of `"`, `'`, `\x00`, or `\`. The replacement will effectively remove any precending backslahes.

You need 4 backslashes in your regular expression. Two backslashes (`\\`) will lead to one backslash (`\`) inside the regular expression string because the PHP interpreter uses backslashes to escape special characters like `"` or `\`. For the same reason you will need two backslahes inside your regular expression.

Or explained the other way around: To gain `\+` as regular expression, you have to add a backslash to tell PCRE that the one backslash is not for escaping the `+`. To get `\\+` as a string you will also need to add one backslash before each backslash to tell the PHP interpreter that you don't want to escape the second backslash with the first.

source code: `\\\\+`

inside regular expression string: `\\+`

pattern matches: `\+`

Comment: Thanks. It works. Also you can see my answer with str_replace.

Answer (score 2):

Replace 2 or more consecutive slashes to a single slash
`preg_replace('/\\\\+/','\\',$str);`

Comment: In order to replace front slashes:
`preg_replace('/\/\/+/', '/', $string);`

Answer (score 2):

Alternative way.

```
$s = 't\est\\\\\\\\\\\\stri\\\\\"\\\\\'\\\\0\\\\ng';
$s = preg_replace('~\\\\+~', '\\', $s);
$s = str_replace(array('\\"', '\\\'', '\\0'), array('"', '\'', "\0"), $s);
```

Comment: str_replace will do more than one replacement, so you can replace multiple backslashes, too. I couldn't get it to work with str_replace, but if you like, go for it. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try these:

```
preg_replace("/\\+(['\"\0\\])/", "$1", $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with [stripslashes](http://nl.php.net/stripslashes)? It accounts for slashes that escape a "special" character and removes "extra" slashes.

Comment: 1) I can have a lot of slashes and I need to run stripslashes in loop 2) stripslashes converts `\a` to `a`. It's incorrect